# Issues with jmxMBeanExporter and duplicate kafkaStreamsTopology with Spring Cloud Streams Horsham/Hoxton

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud-stream

When working to update my app from Spring Boot 2.1.X to 2.3.X and Spring Cloud Streams (kafka stream version) from 2.1.2 to 3.0.8 (Fishtown to Hoxton) I encountered the following:

```
2020-09-03 14:21:00.059 ERROR [main] org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication -  - Application run failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jmxMBeanExporter' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/endpoint/jmx/JmxEndpointAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.jmx.JmxEndpointExporter]: Factory method 'jmxMBeanExporter' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to map duplicate endpoint operations: [MBean call 'kafkaStreamsTopology'] to topologyEndpoint
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:655)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:635)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1336)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1176)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:556)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:516)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:226)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:322)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:897)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:879)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:551)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:143)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:758)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:750)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1237)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226)
    at com.myapp.MyAppApplicationKt.main(MyAppApplication.kt:33)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.jmx.JmxEndpointExporter]: Factory method 'jmxMBeanExporter' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to map duplicate endpoint operations: [MBean call 'kafkaStreamsTopology'] to topologyEndpoint
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:650)
    ... 20 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to map duplicate endpoint operations: [MBean call 'kafkaStreamsTopology'] to topologyEndpoint
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.annotation.EndpointDiscoverer.assertNoDuplicateOperations(EndpointDiscoverer.java:234)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.annotation.EndpointDiscoverer.convertToEndpoint(EndpointDiscoverer.java:201)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.annotation.EndpointDiscoverer.convertToEndpoints(EndpointDiscoverer.java:182)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.annotation.EndpointDiscoverer.discoverEndpoints(EndpointDiscoverer.java:125)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.annotation.EndpointDiscoverer.getEndpoints(EndpointDiscoverer.java:117)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.endpoint.jmx.JmxEndpointAutoConfiguration.jmxMBeanExporter(JmxEndpointAutoConfiguration.java:95)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154)
    ... 21 common frames omitted
```

Although removing the `@ComponentScan(...)` I had on the core application silenced the above issue it lead to "missing bean!" issues as I was no longer including beans from a `commons` package.

What is causing this error? And how do I fix it?

Answer (score 4):

After finding no luck searching for `jmxMBeanExporter`, broken `@ComponentScan(...)`, and/or `kafkaStreamsTopology`. I focused in on the library changes and started reading Spring Cloud Stream Github issues.

My issue was resolved by following this [comment from a library author](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka/issues/895#issuecomment-634905957)

> ...I just ran into this exact issue with another application on IntelliJ (with `Hoxton.BUILD-SNAPSHOT`) and was able to fix that by disabling the JMX agent in the Run profile on the IDE. Please try that as a solution. I am closing this issue now. Feel free to re-open if need be.

Sure enough disabling `Enable JMX agent` for the IntelliJ build run resolved the issue.

[image: The fix disable enable JMX agent in IntelliJ]

Comment: does anyone know what's the root cause for this problem?

Comment: Adding to the SEO for this answer, which resolved my problem. Here's the error I was getting:
"required a bean of type 'javax.management.MBeanServer' that could not be found"